What “C’s” did Tugger borrow from the Pin?
Near the end of Brick (2005), Brendan helps Tugger and the Pin negotiate.

The Pin: I want full assurance that any heat from Emily and Dode is on just you. I don’t even want my name pulled into this shindig. Second, you owe me six C’s. No rush, but I want your shake that they’ll be home in not too much time.
Brendan: That’s square. You did ’em after all. Lay low, it’ll blow over. Stick on this, one of you will dish it to bury the other, you’ll both get the rap. As for the six, did you borrow it?
Tugger: Yeah.
Brendan: Then you owe it. Shouldn’t need to shake on that.
Tugger: Okay to both.

What was meant here by “six C’s”?

A "C" is American slang for a hundred dollar bill. This dates back to the 1800s and references the prominent letter C (for 'century') that used to be printed onto reserve bills of the era.
Tugger has evidently borrowed $600 and assures Brendan he plans to return this money to Pin, per whatever agreement they already have in place, so no additional terms are needed.



C: One hundred dollars (US), (1839)

The two C’s got him. — Mickey Spillane, Kiss Me Deadly, p. 78, 1952
I rolled her for a C, man. — John Rechy, City of Night, p. 140,1963
A fin for a number-five cap. A sixteenth for a "C." A piece for a grand.
— Iceberg Slim (Robert Beck), Pimp, p. 128,1969

Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English.

Note that all three examples above are from criminals. These slang terms are used to provide some imagined level of protection from the law since a lawyer could argue that the speaker didn't mean money, but in fact was referring to something else.

In the original treatment we have an additional line to corroborate that it's money that's owed.

I don't know. We'd have to square everything between us. He owes me some money.


This is corroborated by a quote in the script (available at Rian Johnson’s website).
“Alright. So he’s a hot head. So you don’t want him on your side, at least
let’s have a pow wow fore we start digging trenches. Maybe we can all walk away amiable enemies. What would it take?”
“I don’t know. We’d have to square everything between us. He owes me some money.”
(This last line isn’t present in the final film.)
